# g++ error 0xc000007b when compiling program with iostream

Tags: c++, windows, g++, iostream

I have a C++ program which I am compiling on a x64 machine running Windows 10 with g++ x86_64-win32-seh-rev2 v7.1.0, using the command `g++ -g main.cpp`. When I run my program, [I get the error 0xc000007b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tctS.png). This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine. When I run it in gdb, it runs fine.

I have seen other posts where there are dlls being used that do not support the architecture, but I don't think I am using any dlls in this application, unless they are being added by g++

Comment: It will probably be faster for you to learn Linux, and install a Linux distribution that already comes prepackaged and properly configured with the latest version of gcc, rather than try to figure out what specifically is broken in your specific installation of Windows.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, To be fair, it's even faster (given that W10 is already running) to open a WSL Bash shell and use it from there.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a dll that's required, maybe for the runtime? Dependency walker would tell you. It could also be an overzealous virus checker.